# Error with AS400 DB connection and result set data not deleted when next call is made

Tags: java, websphere, messagebroker

I'm trying to connect to an `AS400 DB` from  a Java compute node but getting errors. Can you please advise.

My testing scenario is:

1. My broker flow is triggered every 9sec to run a select and delete row in `AS400 DB`
2. Connect to `AS400 DB` using `JDBC_TransactionType.MB_TRANSACTION_AUTO`.

   try {
       //get connection to the AS400 server
       if (conn == null)
           try { 
               conn = getJDBCType4Connection("AS400db",JDBC_TransactionType.MB_TRANSACTION_AUTO);
               strSelectStoredProcName = (String)getUserDefinedAttribute("SelectStoredProcName");
               result =  new  CDBItaly_CoreSelectCustomerDetails().retrievePPWICustomerDetails(conn, strSelectStoredProcName);

   ```
       } catch (SQLException e) {
           //store any error code and description in the environment tree.
           mbElement.createElementAsFirstChild(MbElement.TYPE_NAME_VALUE, "ErrorCode", CDBItalyErrorCodes.CDB_ITALY_0001.toString());
           mbElement.createElementAsFirstChild(MbElement.TYPE_NAME_VALUE, "ErrorDesc", CDBItalyErrorCodes.CDB_ITALY_0001.getErrorDescription());
           catchTerminal.propagate(assembly);
       }
   ```

   } catch(Exception e) {}
3. Get rows from ResultSet once and get right results - OK
4. Delete all rows from the table using rs.DeleterOW, meaning that the ResultSet should return nothing next time.
5. Try fetching again (now it should return 0 rows). But it returns the exact same rows as in step 2, even though the database table is empty.
6. If I restart the broker flow it works fine again.

Now if I change the code as follows :

```
try {
    //get connection to the AS400 server            
    if (conn == null) {
        conn = getJDBCType4Connection("AS400db",JDBC_TransactionType.MB_TRANSACTION_AUTO);
    }

    try { 
        strSelectStoredProcName = (String)getUserDefinedAttribute("SelectStoredProcName");
        result =  new  CDBItaly_CoreSelectCustomerDetails().retrievePPWICustomerDetails(conn, strSelectStoredProcName);

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        //store any error code and description in the environment tree.
        mbElement.createElementAsFirstChild(MbElement.TYPE_NAME_VALUE, "ErrorCode", CDBItalyErrorCodes.CDB_ITALY_0001.toString());
        mbElement.createElementAsFirstChild(MbElement.TYPE_NAME_VALUE, "ErrorDesc", CDBItalyErrorCodes.CDB_ITALY_0001.getErrorDescription());
        catchTerminal.propagate(assembly);
} catch(Exception e){}
```

I get an error: `java.sql.SQLException` the connection does not exist

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so in the first example because you don't have any curly braces the whole try block is executed if conn == null.

This means if you had a connection before the query itself is not being executed and the result variable will point to whatever it did before any of your code was executed.

In the second example we can see that conn query is being executed because you get an exception when you try to use the connection. I suspect that in this case conn was not equal to null and you had a reference to the connection already when you entered this code.

So my guess is that you are managed to cache a reference to a connection that gets closed, hence the SQLException text. I would try removing the if(conn == null) condition entirely and always trying to get the connection. Broker will manage and cache these connections for you anyway.